# DejaDup cant restore Backup with 'Unkown Error'

Tags: backup

This is the tracebak that I get,

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/app/bin/duplicity", line 87, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/app/bin/duplicity", line 70, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1568, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 1651, in do_backup
    restore(col_stats)
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 736, in restore
    restore_get_patched_rop_iter(col_stats)):
  File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/duplicity/dup_main.py", line 788, in restore_get_patched_rop_iter
    file_names.append(backup_set.volume_name_dict[vol_num])
 KeyError: 280
```

I recently made a fresh install of `22.04`, but had to downgrade to `21.10` again. The backup was working before I started upgrading everything.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: What version of Deja-Dup do you have installed? In case that 21.10 has an older version you could try installing the snap version `snap install deja-dup` and run that with `snap run deja-dup`.

Comment: Did you run the backup with `sudo`? Also check permissions on the mountpoints that you back up to, if it isn't Google.

Comment: Some backups (such as a lot of files if you are trying to backup up the `/` (root) of your hard drive) require super user permissions. To run DejaDup as sudo, go to the terminal, and run `sudo deja-dup` Also, judging by the traceback, it seems that there may be some bugs in the code of what you are trying to backup. If the above doesn't work, try excluding those packages.

Comment: @Béné I have version `43.2`. Im going to be honest here, when I backed up I justed opened the GUI and pressed backup. I do not know whether this amount to restoring/backupping in sudo.

However, oddly enough I could restore the backup from one day before, but not the latest day.

Comment: @Serkan Ah, then that's not it, that should be the latest version. You could try manually restoring the backup: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help/Restore/WorstCase Or you could try talking to the Deja-Dup devs directly at: https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/issues/new?issuable_template=Help%20Request

Comment: Did you find a solution? Deja-Dup (v42.9) suddenly started throwing this error on Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: @Jaydin sorry for my late reply. No - No I didnt. Submitted a report on Github, but no solution. Did you fix it?

Comment: @Serkan yes, I did not receive that error today. I changed the backup location/folder, so DejaDup/Duplicity created a new backup at the new location without any errors. I will post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the backup location:

- Open Backup (Deja-Dup)
- Select the Three lines on top right -> Preferences -> Location
- Change Storage Location and/or Folder. Changing the folder worked for me.